# Get the first list of a string

Tags: php

hi i have a variable $word and I need to get the first list of the string it's holding. ex: $word = "guess";
$iso_string = "g";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the trick.

`$word[0]`

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
$word[0]
```

Reference:

- [PHP manual on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
- [PHP String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php)